# How to set border for merged cells in Pear Excel

Tags: php, spreadsheet-excel-writer

How to set the border for merged cells in the PHP Pear Spreadsheet Excel writer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can writeBlank on the merged cell and apply your pre-defined format.

For Example

```
$format = [Define your format over here]

$worksheet->writeString( 0, 1, "some Text", $format);
$worksheet->writeBlank( 0, 2, $format);
$worksheet->setMerge(0,1,0,2);
```